# IntelliJ Java Type Renderers for Eclipse Collections with primitives

Tags: java, intellij-idea, eclipse-collections

I have found [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) very useful. Especially collections for primitive types (for example: IntObjectHashMap).
Unfortunately there is a problem with rendering these collections in IntelliJ IDEA debugger.

Let's have a sample code:

```
import org.eclipse.collections.impl.map.mutable.primitive.IntObjectHashMap;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntObjectHashMap<String> eclipseMap = new IntObjectHashMap<>(4);
        eclipseMap.put(1, "one");
        eclipseMap.put(2, "two");

        HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>(4);
        hashMap.put(1, "one");
        hashMap.put(2, "two");

        System.out.println("" + eclipseMap);
        System.out.println("" + hashMap);
    }
}
```

Here we have a debugger variables view:

[image]

As we can see JDK HashMap is rendered perfectly, but `IntObjectHashMap` Eclipse Collection is not.

The situation is even worse when I drop down values for Eclipse Collection:

[image]

As we can see - there is no `one` element on the values list.

You can say: OK, as a workaround, you can use standard `toString` renderer available in IntelliJ:

[image]

Unfortunately in my case it is not the case since my collections have tens of millions of elements.

**So my question is:**

Anybody know a place / a project where I can find IntelliJ Java type renderers for Eclipse Collections for primitive types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create a type renderer, for example like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

@Egor answer is almost perfect :)
It works great, but for small collections only.

Let me describe the problem with @Egor solution. Let's have a look at the example:

```
import org.eclipse.collections.impl.map.mutable.primitive.IntObjectHashMap;

public class Test3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int CAPACITY = 20_000_000;
        IntObjectHashMap<String> eclipseMap = new IntObjectHashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++) {
            eclipseMap.put(i, Integer.toString(i));
        }

        System.out.println("Hello world.");
    }
}
```

Now run it - everything is OK.
Now put the breakpoint at line `System.out.println("Hello world.")` and execute this program in the debug mode.

We will be slapped by OutOfMemoryError (because IntelliJ calls toString method on this collection):

[image]

To solve this problem we need to set `When rendering a node` -> `Use following expression` - for example like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have not tried it on big collections